# Using jQuery tablesorter with javascript table array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, tablesorter

I am trying to use the jQuery plugin tablesorter (tablesorter.com) on an html table that is generated by a javascript array when my page loads. The table gets styled, by the table won't sort when the column headers are clicked.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.11.4/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/jquery/tablesorter/themes/blue/style.css">
  <style>
  </style>
  <script>
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( "table" ).tablesorter();

        $( "p" ).click( function() {
            $( this ).hide();
        });
    });

    $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });

  </script>
  <script>
    var frameData = [
      ["Phoenix Smasher", 15],
      ["Bone Breaker", 16],
      ["DeathFist", 60],
      ["Thruster", 20],
      ["S Jab", 10]
    ];

    function pageLoad() {
      var t = "";
      t += "<thead>";
      t += "<tr>";
      t += "<th>Move</th>";
      t += "<th>Start Up</th>";
      t += "</tr>";
      t += "</thead>";
      t += "<tbody>";
      for (var i = 0; i < frameData.length; i++) {
        t += "<tr>";
        t += "<td>" + frameData[i][0] + "</td><td>" + frameData[i][1] + "</td>";
        t += "</tr>";
      }
      t += "</tbody>";
      document.getElementById("frameTable").innerHTML = t;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="pageLoad()">
  <p>Click the table headers to sort the array in descending order.</p>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div id="demo"></div>
  <table id="frameTable" class="tablesorter">
  </table>

  <p>jQuery test. This text will disappear on click.</p>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</body>
</html>
```

**What I've tried:** Oddly enough, when I get rid of the javascript array and place actual html table data in between the `<table>` and `</table>` tags, the tablesorter plugin works fine. Also, I've tried re-arranging the array and `pageLoad()` function with the jQuery code, with no luck at all.

Any idea how to get this to work?

The page is on my server: http://sketchcarellz.com/multiArray.html

Comment: Is that going to solve the problem? I'll try to do that now.

Comment: I placed all of my `pageLoad` and array code under `$( document ).ready`, and that did not solve the issue. I then tried to place all of my code in `( document ).ready` under `pageLoad`, and that did not work either. Your suggestion does not contribute to a solution for my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you are initializing the plugin before the table is built.

Switch the order of execution. To do this only use one load handler to be assured you know the sequencing

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
     pageload();
    // table is build, call plugin
    $( "table" ).tablesorter();
});
```

Comment: there is a lot more under the hood than just what you see in the html. Internal caching inside plugin etc

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create a table from JSON using the the [Build Table Widget](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-build-table.html)

Make sure you include the build table widget:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.0/js/widgets/widget-build-table.min.js";></script>
```

If you have an array of values, you can add the header to the first row like this:

```js
var tableData = [
  // header
  [ "Move", "Start Up"],
  // rows
  [ "Phoenix Smasher", 15],
  [ "Bone Breaker",    16],
  [ "DeathFist",       60],
  [ "Thruster",        20],
  [ "S Jab",           10]
]
```

Then pass the array and some params to the build source options in to the `widgetOptions`  like this:

```js
$("#jsonTable").tablesorter({
  theme: 'materialize',
  widgets: ['zebra'],
  widgetOptions: {
    build_type: 'array',          // can sometimes be detected if undefined
    build_source: tableData,
    build_headers: {
      rows    : 1,                // Number of header rows from the array
      widths  : [ '70%', '20%' ]  // set header cell widths
    },
    build_footers : {
      rows    : 0,                // Number of header rows from the array
    },
  }
});
```

#### Demo in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/f18s5mwp/) & StackSnippets:

```js
var tableData = [
  // header
  [ "Move" , "Start Up"],
  // rows
  [ "Phoenix Smasher", 15],
  [ "Bone Breaker", 16],
  [ "DeathFist", 60],
  [ "Thruster", 20],
  [ "S Jab", 10]
]

$("#jsonTable").tablesorter({
  theme: 'materialize',
  widgets: ['zebra'],
  widgetOptions: {
    build_type: 'array',      // can sometimes be detected if undefined
    build_source: tableData,
    build_headers: {
      rows    : 1,         // Number of header rows from the array
      widths  : [ '70%', '20%' ] // set header cell widths
    },
    build_footers : {
      rows    : 0,         // Number of header rows from the array
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.0/css/theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.0/css/theme.materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.0/js/jquery.tablesorter.combined.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.0/js/widgets/widget-build-table.min.js"></script>


<div id="jsonTable"></div>
```

**Further Reading**:

- [Issue #31 - Tablesorter + json data support](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/31)
- [Issue #500 - Initializing tablesorter from a JavaScript array or JSON data](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/500)
- [SO - Creating HTML table from JSON with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34888340/1366033)