# Creating HTML table from JSON with JQuery, trying to sort with Tablesorter plugin, but not working

Tags: jquery, html, json, tablesorter

I'm having some trouble getting tablesorter to work with an HTML table that's being created with JQuery from JSON data. I get the table created, and the column headers highlight when I click them but it doesn't sort the data. The JQuery that creates the table is this:

```
function buildHtmlTable() {
     var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList);

     for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
         var row$ = $('<tr/>');
         for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
             var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];

             if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }

             row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
         }
         $("#excelDataTable").append(row$);
     }
 }

function addAllColumnHeaders(myList) {
     var columnSet = [];
     var headerTr$ = $('<thead/>');

     for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
         var rowHash = myList[i];
         for (var key in rowHash) {
             if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1){
                 columnSet.push(key);
                 headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
             }
         }
     }
     $("#excelDataTable").append(headerTr$);

     return columnSet;
 }
```

This builds the table, and has the THEAD and TBODY tags required by tablesorter.
I then create the table and run the tablesorter function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  buildHtmlTable();
  $('#excelDataTable').tablesorter();

});
```

This is the HTML:

```
<body>

  <table id="excelDataTable" class="tablesorter">
  </table>

</body>
```

When I click on the table headers they get highlighted by a blue box (like they're aware of being clicked), but they do not sort. I thought it had something to do with created the table dynamically,  as the tablesorter will work with a hardcoded HTML table. But for this application I will be getting JSON data and will need to build out the table based on what I receive. The table data will not change dynamically, its just created that way. Any help appreciated, and will definitely post back further details if needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see where you are creating the `thead` but where are you creating the `tbody`? It seems like the table rows (`<tr>`)are getting appended to the `<table>` element directly via `$("#excelDataTable").append(row$);`  instead  of getting appended to `<table><tbody>`...?

Comment: If you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), it includes a [build widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-build-table.html) which can load and build your table from an array, CSV, or JSON data.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys! I wondered about the table it built too. When I inspected the HTML that code generated it looked OK. I can double-check that though. I'm going to try that build widget you linked Mottie.

Comment: That widget worked great Mottie, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Mottie's suggestion to use the build widget worked for me. I changed the file format containing the data from JSON to CSV.
Javascript is

```
$(function() {
  $('#excelDataTable').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra'],
    widgetOptions: {
      // *** build widget core ***
      build_type      : 'csv',
      build_source    : { url: 'data.txt', dataType: 'text' },
      build_headers   : {
        widths  : ['50%']
      }
    }
  });
});
```

And HTML is simply

```
<body>

  <div id="excelDataTable"></div>

</body>
```

Also, I did have to do some tweaking to get chrome to use a locally hosted file, however this worked straight away in IE.